# WiFi Mesh Network: Meshing support on adapter as a Client

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, mesh-networking

So I have a Wifi Mesh Network (Unifi) and I want to know if my Wifi Adapter need to support meshing or any other technical function to use the Meshing of the existing Network as a Client. I have a Debian based System that has to be mobile, but I'm not sure if a need to activate some setting to use the meshing of my Unifi Wifi Network.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple minded mesh (Cisco wireless plus Ubiquiti Access Point (same SSIDs).

No changes to Wireless Adapters required:  Computer, iPhone, and IOT devices.

Intel Wireless (Windows) and Panda Wireless  (Kali).

Handover from main floor (Cisco) to second floor (Ubiquiti) is not instant but the handover is complete in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Probably nice to hear but it would be optimal if the crossing is fluent and an handover would take like less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Professional gear might handover that fast . My wireless always works. Handover just affects signal strength.  Zero loss of connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I think there maybe confusion between **mesh** and **active handover**.

To me, mesh just means using the same SSID for the entire network.  But the android mobile (and possibly Apple too) will hang on till the bitter end to the AP it first connects to.

To make it better you have to enable `Active Handover`, where a server (central device) decides which AP the mobile should connect to.  I would not expect this to work with disparate devices without configuration.

Comment: I use the same SSID and my iPhone picks up the Ubiquiti upstairs when I carry it upstairs. I clarified my post. Handover DOES occur and reliably - just not instant.

Comment: Is it possible to do a fluent crossing between the networks, for example if you connect to two AP's simultaneously and let Debian decide which AP to choose?